# Получить частоты из аудио

Tags: java, android, аудио

Получаю массив байт с микрофона:

```
void createAudioRecorder() {
    final AudioRecord recorder = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
            8192, //частота сэмплинга
            AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, //количество каналов
            AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, //формат PCM
            2048);
    final byte[] buffer = new byte[myBufferSize];
    recorder.startRecording();
    final boolean isRecording = true;
    Thread recordingThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            while (isRecording) {
                // читаем байты с микрофона в буфер
                recorder.read(buffer, 0, 1024); //читаем кусками по 1024
                //дальше что-то с этим делаем (видимо раскладываем на частоты)

                for (int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println(buffer[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    });
    recordingThread.start();
}
```

В данном случае `buffer` - это массив байт.
Не могу разобраться, как из массива "цифр" можно получить частоты аудио?

Массив имеет примерно следующий вид:

```
...
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: -23
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: -1
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 4
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 0
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 7
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 0
...
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 20
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 0
2020-07-20 21:16:27.699 19289-19330/? I/System.out: 33
...
```

Comment: Прекратите использование тега `android-studio`, в следующий раз буду минусовать! И принятые ответы здесь принято помечать как принятые (помечать галочкой слева от ответа)

Answer (score 1):

Вы запрашиваете поток данных в виде `AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT` - что означает в переводе на нормальный язык [PCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulse-code_modulation) - *Pulse Code Modulation* - грубо говоря оцифрованная амплитудная модуляция сигнала. Простая синусоида (то есть 1 частотный сигнал) в PCM выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для того, чтобы получить частоты вам надо сделать Фурье преобразование, точнее FFT (Fast Fourier Transformation)

Например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23532379/how-to-resolve-frequency-from-pcm-samples)